# Weird KeyError (Python)

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests

So, I have to work with this JSON (from URL):

```
{'player': {'racing': 25260.154000000017, 'player': 259114.57700000296}, 'farming': {'fishing': 33783.390999999414, 'mining': 29048.60500000002, 'farming': 25334.504000000023}, 'piloting': {'piloting': 25570.18800000001, 'cargos': 3080.713000000036, 'heli': 10433.977000000004}, 'physical': {'strength': 198358.86700000675}, 'business': {'business': 50922.88500000005}, 'trucking': {'mechanic': 2724.5620000000004, 'garbage': 755.642999999997, 'trucking': 223784.99700000713, 'postop': 1411.4190000000006}, 'train': {'bus': 669.1940000000001, 'train': 1363.805999999999}, 'ems': {'fire': 25449.43400000001, 'ems': 13844.628000000012}, 'hunting': {'skill': 4179.033000000316}, 'casino': {'casino': 18545.526000000027}}
```

It is indeed one line. I am trying to make it so that for example, I can get racing, which is the first one you see. For this, you need go into Player first, and then you can get to Racing. How do I do this?

My current code:

```
def allthethings():
    # Grab all the skills
    geturl = ("http://server.tycoon.community:30120/status/data/" + str(setting_playerid))
    print(geturl)
    a = requests.get(geturl,headers={"X-Tycoon-Key":setting_apikeyTT}).json()
    jsonconverted = (a["data"]["gaptitudes_v"])
    print(jsonconverted)
    # Convert JSON into many, many variables
    Raw_RACR = jsonconverted['player.racing']
    print(Raw_RACR)
```

I believe this is all the code that is needed.
Also, this is the error:

```
KeyError: 'player.racing'
```

Comment: replace that line with `jsonconverted['player']['racing']` does this fix your issue?

Comment: That did it, thank you very very much!

Comment: I've posted it as an answer explaining it in depth, can you choose it as the correct answer?